# SQL Insert on specific column, based on select

Tags: sql, excel, select, insert, case

I'm *really* new at SQL and i'm trying to optimize some reports that are currently on excel files. There is a formula that calculates the difference between dates based on a certain condition (comparing values of the current and next row.

The data looks like this:

```
AppID           Status                  Created Date
281             Default                 1/6/2015
281             Withdrawn By Candidate  1/7/2015
301             Default                 1/8/2015
....
```

The formula compares Application ID in this fashion:
[Excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgPt7.jpg)
So far, I came up with this select, that compares the values of the current and next row.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN AppID = LEAD(AppID) OVER (ORDER BY AppID)
THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [Created Date], LEAD([Created Date]) OVER (ORDER BY AppID)) 
ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, [Created Date], GETDATE()) 
END as Days, * 
FROM Application
```

And it shows the correct results. But when I try to use the update:

```
UPDATE  Application_Days
SET [Days] = (SELECT 
            CASE 
            WHEN AppID = LEAD(AppID) OVER (Partition by AppId ORDER BY AppID) 
               THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, [Created Date], LEAD([Created Date]) OVER (Partition by AppId ORDER BY AppID)) 
               ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, [Created Date], GETDATE()) 
       END
      )
```

it seems that the CASE result is always false.

Any advice? 
Best regards, and thank you for your time!

Edit - The result table would look like this:

```
AppID   Status      Created Date    Days
281     Default     01/06/2015      1
281     Withdrawn   01/07/2015      1157
301     Default     01/08/2015      11
301     CV Review   01/19/2015      37
301     DQ CV Revi  02/25/2015      1108
321     Default     01/07/2015      12
321     CV Review   01/19/2015      29
321     DQ CV Revi  02/17/2015      1116
341     Default     01/07/2015      0
341     CV Review   01/07/2015      12
341     Shortlist   01/19/2015      0
341     CV Review   01/19/2015      37
341     DQ CV Revi  02/25/2015      1108
362     Default     01/07/2015      1157
365     Default     01/02/2015
```

and I'm getting this:

```
AppID   Status          Created Date   Days
281     Default         2015-01-06     1158
281     Withdrawn By C  2015-01-07     1157
301     Default         2015-01-08     1156
301     CV Review       2015-01-19     1145
301     DQ CV Review    2015-02-25     1108
321     Default         2015-01-07     1157
321     CV Review       2015-01-19     1145
321     DQ CV Review    2015-02-17     1116
341     Default         2015-01-07     1157
341     CV Review       2015-01-07     1157
341     Shortlist       2015-01-19     1145
341     CV Review       2015-01-19     1145
341     DQ CV Review    2015-02-25     1108
362     Default         2015-01-07     1157
365     Default         01/02/2015
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can upload your expected output in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was in a hurry. I added the table with the expected results. Thank you!

Comment: Include partition by in  OVER (ORDER BY AppID)